# PHP to MySQL database and back - Strange characters when storing UTF8 characters

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-transfer

I am trying to store my cities streets in a database. The names contain characters like ăîâșț(romanian characters) and öüóőúűéáí (hungarian characters). For example "Agrișelor" is stored as "AgriÃˆÂ™elor".

My code is a mess so I am not posting it, basically I am trying to encode end decode using the built in functions of PHP ('utf8_encode', 'utf8_decode').

I would like to get a function type solution for data input and output.

Edit: I forgot, the webpage displays the names recalled from the database correctly, I am getting this problem only in the stored data.

Comment: Have you tried sticking to UTF8 in the DB and on the webpage?

Comment: Both the webpage and the database are set to utf8
- for the website `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`
- for the database and tables `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)